# Change background color of text box in MS Access form based upon information from query

Tags: microsoft-access, microsoft-access-2010

I have a form that displays data from a table in MS Access 2010 and allows users to change the data in the table; along with other information this table has a list of unique serial numbers.  I would like to have the background color of the serial number change based upon a value in a query.  This query gives information on whether or not a unit passed a test based upon the serial number.  The idea is to have the serial number's background turn green in the form if the unit passes, or red if it fails.

Conditional formatting allows me to change the background color, but I'm struggling as to how to pull data from the query and use that in the conditional formatting as well as display the original table's information.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your query is the data source for the form and your textbox in question is bound to a field in the query. You can set the conditional formatting to Expression Is [Result]='Pass' (or 'Fail').